# scale entire document

Tags: pdf, scale

Is there a simple way to scale the dimensions of my entire document?

I'm trying to make a A0 sized poster, but I'm finding it is much easier to work with an A4 size document, since that way I don't have to adjust the size of figure titles and footnotes. I would like to simply scale everything up to A0. I can easily do this by opening the output pdf in inkscape and saving adjusting the dimensions there, but I would prefer a latex way of doing this.

I know I can just ask the printers to print everything at 400% scale, but they would prefer that I set the document dimensions.

I have used scalebox for other things, but I don't think that is quite what I want (although I could be wrong).

Comment: you could use pdfpages to include the document scaled in a another A0 document.

Comment: PDF is a scalable format so simply print the A4 document on to A0 use your printer driver to "print to file" so getting a new A0 sized PDf that you can then print directly

Comment: Thanks for the responses, these are both better ideas than using inkscape. I guess there isn't a great way to do this in the original document in latex though?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no one-stop-only solution, if your document includes e.g. some math. But it should not be too difficult. Here in my example you can switch between A4 and A0 paper by commenting out the two optional lines of the document class. For A0 uncomment as well the line `\DeclareMathSizes{60}{48}{36}{36}`.

You can play with it. If fontsize is bigger than 48pt, adapt math sizes.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=48pt, paper=A0,DIV=30
%fontsize=11, paper=a4, DIV=18
]{scrartcl}

\DeclareMathSizes{60}{48}{36}{36}% A0

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, libertine}
\usepackage{microtype, blindtext, array, booktabs}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}




\title{Titel}
\subtitle{Longer subtitle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle{}

\blindtext{}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.4\textwidth}}
    $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ & Given is a square of 5 $\times$ 5 squares on squared
                       paper. Construct a square of an area of 50 squares.\\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

More troubesome ist the layout of the paper itself. But the komascript bundle offers a DIV-factor. With a little bit of testing I got exactly the same word wrap on the two different paper sizes.

### EDIT

It seems that the redefinition of math sizes is not necessary if you load, as done here, the package libertinust1math. So this might be the easiest solution, but it depends on the fonts you use.